# Flutter Streambuilder pause

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, stream-builder

I have an active page with a streambuilder, I need to pause the stream momentarily, then reactivate it, can it be done in flutter?

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('groups')
                .where("participants", arrayContains: currentUserId)
                .where("lastUpdate", isGreaterThan: lastFetchTimestamp)
                .orderBy('lastUpdate', descending: true)
                .limit(30),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) { 
    if (snapshot.hasError)
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    else
      return Text('OK');
  }, 
)
```

When I change page I would like to PAUSE the stream

```
// PAUSE STREAM THEN

 Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Chat())
);
```

THANKS.

Comment: Your question should be how to cancel `Firestore` request.